# sql query relative searching to previous searched words

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have list of word in table. I want to search for all records contain e.g. book and books, pen and pens, that means, for all the word which ends with 's'. The query should show the word without 's' and the word with 's' too. 
not a query `"SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%s'"` 
schema definition is,

words = `<word, part_of_speech`>

I have to search on 'word'
How can I do this?
The result could be,

```
book
books
pen
pens
```

Its something like, if there is a value in the colum as 'word' and there is another value as 'word'+'s' then show the rows of both 'word' and 'word'+'s'.
I'm using sqlite.

Comment: It would help to state which DBMS this is for?

Comment: `factory` and `factories`; `man` and `men`

Comment: Fish -> Fishes, Mouse -> Mice. Do you account for this transitions to plural? Not really sure what your question is after, do you mean there is a list of words in one table, that you want to use to search another table, using the list in the first table in both singular and plural form?  And for the table being searched, would the matches need to be "whole words" only?

Comment: this is mainly for sqlite DB. in the same table. I want to search all the word with any word and a specific suffix after it. I explain it more in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'book%'
```

will match 'book', 'books', 'bookmark', etc

Comment: its not only on book, but also with other word and an specific suffix.

Comment: can you post your CREATE TABLE script?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "no_en" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "no" VARCHAR NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE, "en" VARCHAR NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE , "part_of_speech" VARCHAR, category INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (category) REFERENCES categories(id) )

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search for only a specific sufix then try

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    words
WHERE
    word = '%s'
    or word = '%s' || 's' #change 's' to any addition you want to try
```

Answer (score 0):

Google the "Porter Stemming Algorithm" and apply it to your data **before** you load it.  This algorithm is as close as you can get to converting not just plurals but many other forms of word to a single word.  e.g., "scholarly" becomes "scholar" and stuff like that.

If that does not meet your quality standards, because it will not trap for "mice" and other examples given in other answers, you will have to find a "stemming file".  I know of no free ones (which does not mean there are none), but the one we use at my shop is part of a commercial package, so I've never had to find a free one.

At any rate, once you have applied the stemming to the words on the way in, you no longer have to search for multiple versions of a word, you just search for the stem.